# Should I create Entity with "natural ID" or should I always use Long as ID in each entity

Tags: java, database-design, entity

During my career I saw two different designs, how to model business objects in DB:

1. Always use Long as ID for entity
2. Choose the most suitable as possible.

And now, we have "Resource" entity which we can download from another service. Each resource contains natural `ID` - email(email is just an example, we can imagine other situation when we should use `String`). And I want to use it as primary ID in database. But my workmates want to create additional property - `Long` id. I am not sure, why should I create this additional property. Of course, DB model is simpler because all entities have the same structure, but I prefer to use `String` id.

What do you think, guys, which model is much better and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am not sure if assuming that an email can be a "Resource"s unique natural ID, since that would mean for every new resource, you need to create a new email and a resource can not read emails, but I know cases, so that may be right.

So to the question:

Impacts

- Numeric IDs are faster to look up, in every case. But since Strings are pretty fast as well (when using appropriate indices) that might be enough for most of applications out there.
- Numeric IDs use less space (which is usually the least problem)
- String IDs are usually preferred in cases where heterogenous systems are involved (which you can see in your example: the service provides the "Resource"s with String id's). One reason for that isthat it's easier to debug, e.g. the user might see with one look, what object is referred to, another reason that Strings are the most common denominator of virtually any system (encoding problems will be there though ^^).
- If you have to do lots of manual jobs in a database, you can type numbers faster, since Strings tend to be longer
- If you use natural IDs it is a pretty common case that the id consists of more than one column. This makes SQL statements longer and more error prone, just as it makes Object Relational Mapper Configurations longer and more error prone.
- You usually have some unique identifier (like an email), that but might change over time (people marry ^^). In those cases it is quite common to add some artifical id's as well (have both)

In your case you do not have a choice (?) other than use that string id to communicate with this service, so you at least must have this as well.

So now for my own oppinion: I think as a developer, you have less work and less problems with numeric IDs, though debugging is a little harder. As a database administrator if you have only one column it does not matter if it's String or Long, since it does not complicate joins. As long as the String is immutable, e.g. never changes, you are allright. If it can change it will definitely give you lots of headaches as an administrator (and the stupid developer won't care a bit ^^). If it might change over time, use numeric IDs.

Answer (score 1):

I agree in principal that you should use natural IDs where possible, though in this case email is potentially not a good candidate. Natural IDs should be immutable, i.e. they should never change. If there is any probability that the system would need to change/disassociate an email from a resource, you're essentially changing the identity of the record.

If it were me, and there were no other potential natural IDs; use a unique number. In this case it is not adding any unnecessary complexity, and leaves the design open for future changes to requirements around the email property.

Answer (score 1):

Michal,

Email and such character data columns may not be the right choice for ID as the case sensitivity  depends on the database implementation and/or collation being used. Do you want user@server.com and USER@SERVER.COM to give you the same result? Whether it is possible or not depends on your choice of database/OS/collation. When you have character data based IDs, you silently push these concerns from the application to the database administration & collation config.

This might be good as it is only a one time activity and your DB admin can set it up for you but more often than not, you have to maintain seperate DB scripts for different OS & databases.

In my view, there is no thumb rule for this and you have to make the best judgement depending upon the situation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the arguments already mentioned, you can search for "surrogate key" or visit the Wikipedia's page on this topic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key which lists many pros and cons.